# Sencha Touch 2 native packager failing with multiple "Copy operation failed" errors

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Trying to package my Sencha Touch 2 web app in a native wrapper for iOS.  I'm following the instructions (which seem slightly off or incomplete), but I'm getting a massive number of "Copy operation failed" errors during the build command execution.

The name of my app is "Tally" and I'm using the command line "sencha package build iOS/configFile.json".

My configFile.json is as follows:

```
{   
    "applicationName":"Tally",
    "applicationId":"com.mobyus.tally",
    "bundleSeedId":"3725XYGG8Y",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "iconName":"icon.png",
    "inputPath":"../",
    "outputPath":"../../iOS/Tally",
    "configuration":"Debug",
    "platform":"iOS",
    "deviceType":"iPhone",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

The error codes I'm getting look like the following, but there are hundreds (possibly thousands) of them:

> Copy operation failed src=on.i
>   dst=./build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/build/iOS/Tally.app/webapp/.hg/store/data/build/production/deltas/resources/css/app.css/3d83eee2cc226dc28a3cebf9df631c09175b839f.json.i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed.  Not really exactly sure, but I think the issue was a mismatch between the version I was using to package the app (Sencha CMD) and the web app which was generated using Sencha 2.0.  I recreated the app under Sencha 2.1 and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Yes, 2.0 was not compatible with Cmd - only >=2.1:

  - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command